# Binding in MvvmCross from a view's codebehind

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

For a XAML view, I have it hooking onto `this.ViewModel.PropertyChanged` like so:

```
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentImage")
        DoStuff();
};
```

This is because XAML is not flexible enough for me to achieve what I'd like directly without codebehind, and also because it's code that is purely related to WinRT/XAML and not the core portable project.

However during the view's constructor, the `ViewModel` property is null, thus it was worked around like so:

```
this.Loaded += (s2, e2) =>
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentImage")
        DoStuff();
};
```

I figure this (in addition to using a string to refer to a property) is probably not very clean, and there probably should be a better way to achieve what I'd like. Is there a more ideal approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with MvxPropertyChangedListener, as mentioned in [Stuart's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100792/binding-in-mvvmcross-from-a-xaml-views-codebehind#comment26512144_18101075):

```
new MvxPropertyChangedListener(ViewModel).Listen<TOfProperty>(
    () => ViewModel.SomeProperty,
    () =>
    {
        // Do something
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. Anytime I want to bind a simple property change to something that has complex business affects that require accessing view state I do something like this [for others, the equivalent on iOS is set.Bind(this).For(ViewProperty).To(nameof(ViewModel.Property)].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better approach.  Typically, people use Josh Smith's [PropertyObserver](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/).

This is the first I have heard of MvvmCross, though.  I've developed my own cross-platform MVVM framework which includes a class that fulfills the same function as Josh Smith's PropertyObserver.  I wonder if MvvmCross doesn't already have something like it, too.

Comment: There is a `MvxPropertyChangedListener.cs` helper class - and also several extension method helpers too - see source in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxPropertyChangedListener.cs - **note** that the Mvx property changed listener uses `WeakReference`s within its implementation - this is very important on the Xamarin iOS and Mac platforms (and still somewhat important on Windows and Android too) as it helps prevent memory leaks